# Why does the input return empty?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the input problem which is as follows:

1. On entering the screen, if you already have some data in the input and typing with this data, the value returns me empty in js ..
2. If the input is empty, and when typing something, the first digit is empty.

```
<div class="form-group EGLF pb-3">
    <input type="text" id="FLUI" class="form-control FI EFLI" autocomplete="on" autofocus required>
    <label class="EFL">Usuário</label>
    <span class="EFHL"></span>
    <span class="EFBL"></span>
    <div class="FMFIFL mt-2 ml-1">Por favor, Insira um nome de usuário!</div>
</div>
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const username = document.getElementById('FLUI'),
        userPassword = document.getElementById('FLUPI');

    username.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
        if (username.value.length > 0) {
            const regexp = new RegExp(/[a-z]/g);
            console.log(username.value)
            console.log(regexp.test(username.value))
        }
    });
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` gets updated **after** the `keypress` event has been processed. This lets you use `preventDefault()` to stop the `value` from updating.

Use the `keyup` event if you want to run a function after the `value` has updated.